# How to have a a Key-Value pair for a SharePoint lookup column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have two lists:

**Projects Master**

| ID | Project ID | Project Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P-001 | Project A | ... |
| 2 | P-002 | Project B | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Budget**

| Budget ID | Project ID | Amount | Project Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ***P-001*** | 500,000 | ***Project A*** | ... |
| 2 | ***P-002*** | 1,000,000 | ***Project B*** | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Project ID is the lookup column within Budget.

When I enter a new row within Budget, I see the Project ID dropdown with all probable values. Seeing just the Project ID is cryptic. Can I somehow have Project Name as the display value, but have Project ID as the actual value that gets selected? Or maybe have the text box display a concatenation of Project ID-Project Name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce this. It can be achieved by integrating your form with Power Apps. You could set the "DefaultSelectedItems" and "Items" properties of "DataCardValue3"(datacardvalue of project name field) to display the values corresponding to the additional field.

"DefaultSelectedItems" property:

```
LookUp(test1,DataCardValue2.Selected.Value='Project ID')
```

"Items" property:

```
Filter(test1,DataCardValue2.Selected.Value='Project ID')
```

"test1" is the source list of look up column.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could update your Project ID so that the lookup is pointing to the Project Name AND then also include the Project ID as an additional column that will also get fetched. You can then put the Project Name in the "New form" so that the users will have something meaningfull to choose from and then display both the Prjoct Name and the Project Number in the list/web parts.

That should do the trick.